# How to fetch order details using order id in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2.2

I need to fetch **comment** field which is present in **core table** named **sales_order_status_history** using order id. And how to add comment programmatically in sales\order page in Backend.Please provide me a solution.

Image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Observer -

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="mymodule_controller_success_action" instance="Vendorname\modulename\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```

and in app\code\Vendorname\modulename\MyObserver.php file add code -

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\mudulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Captcha\Observer\CaptchaStringResolver;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     echo $orderId = $order->getId();
     $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');

     print_r("Catched event succssfully !"); exit;

     echo "Here you can set your comment";
    }

}
```

Comment: Is observer the only way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use below code

1.etc/event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
            <observer name="namespace_modulename_observer_getorder" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Observer\Getorder" />
      </event>
</config>
```

2.Observer\Getorder.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Observer;

class Getorder implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId[0]);
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getData()); exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: where did i call this Getorder.php file, to see the output

Comment: you need to create custom module for this and place this file in your module... please check [this link how to create event in magento](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html) and after place order you will see the output..